# How to find last line of dataframe and and create a drop down list for each row till and write to a excel using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dataframe`(df)` like below. I am creating a data validation drop list column called `Status` as `column D` of the excel.

```
A    B    C
12   Car  Yellow
13   Bike Black
14   Car  Red
15   Bike White
```

The issue that I am facing I am only create drop list only for first row of the `column D`.Lets say I have 1000 rows insidethe input excel file then I need to have drop down list against each 1000 rows. How can this done.

**Expect Output (For each row of Column D)**

[image]

**My code**

```
df.to_excel("DropDown.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter') 

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("DropDown.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.write('D1', 'Status')
worksheet.data_validation('D2', {'validate': 'list',
                                  'source': ['Approved',' Rejected','Partially Approved']})
workbook.close()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, you want to add a column that has values for all the rows not only for single row. You can do this by the following steps:*emphasized text*

[image]

If you want to enter at specific column then,
[image]

Comment: I am creating  drop down in the `column D` i.e column name is status . Each row of `column D or Status` should have drop down list having values`{ 'Approved',' Rejected','Partially Approved'}`

Comment: CodeRed, I creating excel output so that users will have drop down list to select for each row of the column. Have look at my current code.

Comment: CodeRed, added a sample output in the question